# How to figure which returned values a function's call actually uses?

Tags: python, return-value, variadic-functions

Given a function `a, b = f(x)`, is there any (pythonic) way to determine which return arguments are actually used? As a pseudo-example, consider

```
def f(x):
    c = common_helper_function(x)
    a = a_complex_function(x,c)
    b = another_complex_function(x,c)
    return a, b
```

where each function call takes a while. If `f` is called e.g. as `_, b = f(x)`, is there any way to detect the irrelevance of `a` inside `f` so `a_complex_function(x,c)` doesn't need to be called? Sure enough I could just write another function `b(x)` which omits that call, but is there another way to achieve this, similar to e.g. MATLAB's [nargout](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/nargout.html) mechanism?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I think if python would be [lazy language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_evaluation), it could be possible, but your code should be changed like

```
def f(x):
    c = common_helper_function(x)
    return a_complex_function(x,c), another_complex_function(x,c)
```

In python, that it's not true

```
def test1():
    print '     simple function'
    return 1

print 'Calling simple function:'
_ = (lambda : test1())()
print 'Calling simple function again:'
_ = (lambda : test1())()

output:
Calling simple function:
    simple function # evaluated once
Calling simple function again:
    simple function # evaluated twice
```

To improve performance, I could suggest you to see two concepts:

[**Memoization**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) - you can keep results of your functions call in the dictionary and not recalculate it once calculated it.
For memoization there's `lru_cache` decorator in `functools` module of python 3 (forpython 2.7 you can download [functools32](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/functools32)).
Here's an example

```
from functools32 import lru_cache

@lru_cache(maxsize=10)
def test2():
    print '     cashed function'
    return 1

print 'Calling cashed function:'
_ = (lambda : test2())()
print 'Calling cashed function again:'
_ = (lambda : test2())()

output:
Calling cashed function:
    cashed function # evaluated once
Calling cashed function again:
                    # not evaluated twice
```

[**Lazy evaluation**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_evaluation). Each result of the function evaluated once when trying to get result of the function and then stored. So in your case it's not evaluated until using variable where you stored function call result. For python 2.7 you can use [lazy.py by Alberto Bertogli](http://blitiri.com.ar/p/python):

```
import lazy

@lazy.lazy
def test3():
    print '     lazy function'
    return 1

print 'Calling lazy function:'
b = (lambda : test3())()
print 'Calling cashed function again:'
b = (lambda : test3())()
print 'Trying to get results:'
print b

output:
Calling lazy function:
Calling cashed function again:
Trying to get results:
    lazy function  # evaluated
1
```

Comment: lazy sounds like the best shot at this, though one should make sure the used values are evaluated as soon as possible in order to avoid difficult to spot bugs later on...

Comment: Indeed, and one could go even further writing an "ultra lazy" module involving something like sympy expressions that only evaluate once really absolutely unavoidable...